# Estimate the power consumption of a C program without hardware

Tags: microcontroller, power, raspberry-pi

I have a C application running on TI CC2650 SENSORTAG microcontroller that performs gesture recognition. Is there any way I can figure out its estimated power usage probably through Raspberry Pi or something, so that I can use it to compare the actual power consumed when I synthesize it on a FPGA? This is an academic project targetted at Hardware acceleration.

Comment: Why not just run it on the pi and measure the power consumed? Its a lot faster (and easier) than formulating some 'estimate' which you have no means of verifying anyway without a physical comparison.

Comment: Is there a way to estimate power? Yes. Will it give a meaningful number? Probably not unless you put so much time and effort into it that it would be easier to build it and measure the power draw. And as Jim pointed out what use is an estimate when you have no idea how accurate it is?

Comment: One ascii character = 0.00015 Volts of power consumption

Comment: @Harrichael That means I have to multiply 0.00015 volts with the number of ASCII characters in my program?

Comment: No, see Olin's answer. The problem with your request is you probably can't even prove if your program, or sub parts of it, terminates or not. Your power output is very much going to depend on your input data.

Comment: @tuskiomi how did you get the value 3 ?

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji: Harrichael's comment is clearly trolling, because **volts is not a unit of power measurement**.  Do yourself a favor and get in the habit of checking dimensional consistency.

Comment: @BenVoigt I missed seeing the units.

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji; even if the units were correct, the number of ASCII characters in your human-readable source code has nothing to do with how it will run once compiled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your equivalent question is to measure the length of a plank without a measure.

You can always eyeball it. The Mic datasheet will provide the current consumption under various conditions, with different peripherals turned on. That's your best bet.

Answer (score 23):

What you are trying to do won't really work.  First a "C program" doesn't consume a particular amount of power.

A particular program performing a particular task on a particular processor may cause a reasonably measurable increase in power draw by that processor, or not.  The power draw of a processor will only change significantly if it would otherwise go into some kind of low power mode if the "program" wasn't running.  On many small systems, not doing one thing only means doing more of other things.  The only effect of running a particular piece of code might be to respond with higher latency to new events, for example.

Even if you can measure a reasonably repeatable power increase in one processor due to running a particular program, that is little indication of anything useful for the same task performed some other way using different technology.  You really should not expect the power increase due to a RPi running a particular program to have a meaningful correlation to the power required to run a FPGA that performs the same function.

Comment: Actually there is a way I have found in some literature. The Microcontroller has a instruction set where each instruction needs a specific amount of power. He can translate his program into assembler code to get all instruction. Than he knows exactly what instructions are executed and can calculate the consumed power by adding the required power for each instruction. The only problem is finding out the power consumption per Instruction. Maybe it can be found in the datasheet or he can ask the TI support for some information

Comment: @S.G The main problem here is the C -> FPGA translation, estimating how much power it would take on a Raspberry Pi is likely easier.

Comment: I agree with you, but i think the translation of the C program is not part of Shankhadeep Mukerji question. I thought he just asked for a way to calculate the power consumption of his C program.

Comment: @S.G: It seems he wants to find the power required on a RPi, then use that to estimate power for the same task implemented in a FPGA.  Basically, that's just plain not going to work.

Comment: @S.G: *Nobody* knows or cares about the power consumption of individual instructions executed. Just think about how the *data* processed will have a great influence.

Comment: @JimmyB: Maybe not many people care about power consumption per instruction, but to be able to compare/modify and enhance the power consumption of a program it is very useful to know the consumption per instruction. Of course the power consumption is influenced by the amount of data that has to be processed by the program. But if the processed data is static, the best idea is to replace all "power-costly" instructions. Here is a good link for further information -->https://www.teisa.unican.es/gim/pub_files/file_326.pdf

Comment: @S.G Sorry for my bad phrasing. With "nobody" I primarily meant "none of the manufacturers of µC's" (plus 99.999% of their customers). Hence, no datasheet and no customer support will have/give any clue.

Comment: @S.G "the power consumption is influenced by the amount of data" - Not only the *amount* of data, but also the *data* itself. The most obvious example: `if ( x == y ) { doSomething(); }` - Vastly different resource use depending on whether or not `x==y` at runtime. More subtle differences may be found in things like `x++`. This may require a little more (or less?) power if x overflows for instance.

Comment: BTW, there are attacks on cryptographic systems leveraging the fluctuations in power consumption of a crypto processor to deduce the value of the secret key it is processing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop My objective is to provide a comparison of sw/hw power usage. Suppose the 'C' program consumes say 10 mW and I run the application on FPGA and see 6mW, then I can say I observed a 40% power reduction.

Comment: Of course, as many people mentioned here, it would depend on the data amount and the data value and when the prog terminates, so even if I measure the power, it would be not an accurate one. I can take that into account.

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji: "Power" is simply a term meaning rate of energy consumption.  Normally we talk about a time rate, and the units are Watts, but for comparing hardware efficiency to software, Watts are useless.  You should look at energy per unit of work (for example, if the work is calculating hashes, the units would be J/million hashes) and leave time out of it entirely.  Throughput in terms of units of work per unit time is interesting but separate.  The last thing you want is to report the hardware uses 100 times the power when it's really 10 times as efficient.